# Center variables PROCESS Moderation model SPSS

Tags: interaction, interpretation, spss, main-effects

I'm currently researching an moderation model in SPSS with Gender as Moderator. When I'm running PROCESS number 1 (moderation) I choose the option “only continuous variables that define products”. Result: interaction effect not significant & main-effect not significant. When running the model with "All variables that define product" the result is: interaction effect not significant & **main effect significant**. How??? I think the best option is only continuous variables because of the categorical moderator... Hope someone can help me with the choice for only continuous variables vs. all variables. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to provide more details about the types of variables in the model and the details of the two models. With interactions there is no single "main effect" coefficient, as the value (and "significance") of a single coefficient depends on the coding of the _predictors with which it interacts_. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/65898/28500), for example. The choice of whether to include interactions between factors should depend on your understanding of the subject matter, not on whether you get a "significant main effect."