# Interpreting multiple regression summary output with (multiple) interactions

Tags: r, mixed-model, multiple-regression, p-value, interaction

This is really basic, but I'm having trouble interpreting the `summary` output of a multiple regression, including one or more interactions with a categorical variable and I couldn't find satisfactory explanations elsewhere. Consider an example based on the `mpg` data set:

```
easypackages::libraries("tidyverse", "nlme", "car")

mod1 <- lm(hwy ~ displ + drv + displ:drv, data = mpg)
Anova(mod1, type = 3)

#> Anova Table (Type III tests)
#> 
#> Response: hwy
#>             Sum Sq  Df F value    Pr(>F)    
#> (Intercept) 7211.6   1 783.660 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> displ       1096.0   1 119.102 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> drv          204.4   2  11.105 2.499e-05 ***
#> displ:drv     86.0   2   4.673   0.01026 *  
#> Residuals   2098.2 228                      
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

This suggests a significant interaction between `displ` and `drv`, i.e. the effect of `displ` will differ, depending on the level of `drv`. Let's look at this in more detail:

```
summary(mod1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = hwy ~ displ + drv + displ:drv, data = mpg)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>    Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
#> -8.489 -1.895 -0.191  1.797 13.467 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  30.6831     1.0961  27.994  < 2e-16 ***
#> displ        -2.8785     0.2638 -10.913  < 2e-16 ***
#> drvf          6.6950     1.5670   4.272 2.84e-05 ***
#> drvr         -4.9034     4.1821  -1.172   0.2422    
#> displ:drvf   -0.7243     0.4979  -1.455   0.1471    
#> displ:drvr    1.9550     0.8148   2.400   0.0172 *  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.034 on 228 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.746,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.7405 
#> F-statistic:   134 on 5 and 228 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

This tells me that the relationship between `displ:drv` for the `drv`-level `r` is significant, while this is not the case for the `drv`-level `f`. Do I understand it correctly that the p-value associated with the `drv`-level `4`, which is the reference level in this model is given in the line of the intercept, i.e. significant in this case? Let's plot the interaction:

```
mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = displ, y = hwy, col = drv)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", lwd = 1.5)
```

[image]

Hmmm, judging by the regression lines and associated scatter, I'm somewhat surprised that the results for `drv`-level `r` are significant, while those for `drv`-level `f` are not. What happens, if we add another term plus associated interaction?

```
mod2 <- lm(hwy ~ displ + drv + cyl + displ:drv + cyl:drv, data = mpg)
summary(mod2)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = hwy ~ displ + drv + cyl + displ:drv + cyl:drv, data = mpg)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -8.2265 -1.8421  0.0316  1.4962 13.3950 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  31.7350     1.2197  26.018  < 2e-16 ***
#> displ        -1.8893     0.6279  -3.009  0.00292 ** 
#> drvf          8.2000     1.8886   4.342 2.14e-05 ***
#> drvr          9.6730     6.3080   1.533  0.12657    
#> cyl          -0.7720     0.4481  -1.723  0.08627 .  
#> displ:drvf    0.3036     1.0626   0.286  0.77533    
#> displ:drvr    3.3796     1.2243   2.761  0.00625 ** 
#> drvf:cyl     -0.8073     0.7415  -1.089  0.27743    
#> drvr:cyl     -2.8897     1.2139  -2.381  0.01812 *  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 2.923 on 225 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7674, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7591 
#> F-statistic: 92.78 on 8 and 225 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

OK, so we now have significant interactions for some levels of both `displ:drv` and `cyl:drv`, but what happened to the results for the reference-level of `drv`, i.e. `4`? Does the p-value shown for the intercept give the significance for both interactions of `displ:drv` and `cyl:drv`, when `drv` equals `4`?

To sum this up:

- Is it correct to interpret p-values for the different levels of an interaction term with a categorical variable separately?
- Is the p-value for the reference level of the categorical variable (in this case `drv`-level `4`) that shown in the line of the intercept of the `summary` output?
- Is that still the case in the presence of multiple interactions?

Comment: To answer your second question: the comparison is between each level and the reference level. In your case, the $p$-value of `displ:drvf` is large because the green and red lines have similar slopes.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to interpret individual coefficients reported by the initial summary of a regression model with interactions tends to lead to confusion. Several similar questions appear on this site each week. My general advice: "Don't try this at home."

With interactions, each higher-level coefficient is a *difference* beyond what you would predict based on the lower-level coefficients. The value of a lower-level coefficient and thus its "*p*-value" and the "statistical signficance" of its difference from 0 depends on how its *interacting* predictors are coded. Yes, you can work those details out. Doing it once or twice does help fix the issues in your mind.

For practical applications, it's better to use well-vetted post-modeling tools rather than trying to figure out the individual coefficients from the model summary. The `Anova()` function in the R [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) provides estimates of statistical significance that consider all levels of a predictor and its interactions, in a way that isn't limited by an imbalanced design. The R [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) provides useful tools for evaluating any combinations of predictor values that you want.

Comment: "The value of a lower-level coefficient and thus its "p-value" and the "statistical signficance" of its difference from 0 depends on how its interacting predictors are coded" - are you referring to recoding the contrasts, mean-centering the predictors and the like?

Comment: @M.Teich yes. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/65898/28500) for discussion, and [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/417029/28500) for an algebraic illustration. The same holds true for changing reference levels of categorical predictors, etc. It's good to work the details through once or twice as you've done, but in practice I tend to ignore the individual coefficients and use post-modeling tools for inference. The [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) is another good choice for combining modeling with post-modeling analysis.